# TypeScript, Promise and Interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I recently started using TypeScript, but I'm stuck in one place and can't find a solution to one problem. Can you answer? How to shorten the code and get rid of the creation of an empty intermediate class PaginatedUserDTO ?

file: paginated-user.dto.ts

```
export class PaginatedUserDTO extends Paginated(UserDTO) {}
```

file: user.service.ts

```
async find(filter?: findArgs): Promise<PaginatedUserDTO> {
    const { first, after, last, before, find } = filter;
    const query = this.User.find(find);
    
    return paginate(query, filter); 
}
```

I tried writing something like:

```
async find(filter?: findArgs): Promise<Type extends Paginated(BusStopDTO)> {
    ...
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Can you send me link to documentation for `Paginated`?

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/resolvers#generics

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctry, `Paginated<T>(classRef: Type<T>)` returns `Type<IPaginatedType<T>>`, so you may try something like

```js
async find(filter?: findArgs): Promise<Type<IPaginatedType<BusStopDTO>>> {
    ...
}
```

Comment me if it didn't work

Comment: https://playcode.io/917061

It didn't work


src/bg/user/user.service.ts:48:14 - error TS4055: Return type of public method from exported class has or is using private name 'Type'.

48   ): Promise<Type<IPaginatedType<UserDTO>>> {